Next js useSearchParams, usePathname and useRouter issue
I have a Next.js project where users can upload properties and apply various filters such as amenities, minPrice, maxPrice, etc.
I created a custom hook to reset specific query parameters when the user clicks a "Reset Filter" button. However, after resetting the filters, some parameters still appear in the URL even though the logs indicate they have been deleted. Here s my code
'use client';
import {
  useSearchParams,
  usePathname,
  useRouter,
} from 'next/navigation';

export function useFilterReset(onClose: () => void) {
  const pathname = usePathname();
  const router = useRouter();
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();

  const handleResetFilter = () => {
    const params = new URLSearchParams(searchParams.toString());
    params.delete('minPrice');
    params.delete('maxPrice');
    console.log('************** propertyType **************');
    console.log('############# BEFORE DELETE ################');
    console.log(params.get('propertyType'));
    params.delete('propertyType');
    console.log('############# AFTER DELETE ################');
    console.log(params.get('propertyType'));

    console.log('************** amenities **************');
    console.log('############# BEFORE DELETE ################');
    console.log(params.get('amenities'));
    params.delete('amenities');
    console.log('############# AFTER DELETE ################');
    console.log(params.get('amenities'));
    router.replace(pathname + '?' + params);
    // onClose();
  };

  return {
    handleResetFilter,
  };
}

Suppose the initial URL is:
http://localhost:3000/properties/map?lat=-26.2476095&lng=28.0873945&neLat=-26.24251187946654&neLng=28.09495803486075&swLat=-26.25713408434988&swLng=28.08018899408635&keywords=india&radios=&placeId=ChIJmeflRr8PlR4RWvO2jWjKfwE&address=South+Hills%2C+Johannesburg+South%2C+South+Africa&amenities=outdoor+space%2Cdryer%2Cpets+allowed%2Claundry+in+building%2Cfurnished%2Ccovered+parking%2Celevator%2Cwasher%2Cstove&propertyType=apartment%2Chouse%2Ctownhouse
Upon executing the reset filter function, the logs indicate that the propertyType and amenities parameters are deleted correctly:
**************** propertyType **************
############# BEFORE DELETE ################
apartment,house,townhouse
############# AFTER DELETE ################
null
************** amenities **************
############# BEFORE DELETE ################
outdoor space,dryer,pets allowed,laundry in building,furnished,covered parking,elevator,washer,stove
############# AFTER DELETE ################
null
owever, after the function executes, the URL still contains the amenities parameter:
http://localhost:3000/properties/map?lat=-26.2476095&lng=28.0873945&neLat=-26.24251187946654&neLng=28.09495803486075&swLat=-26.25713408434988&swLng=28.08018899408635&keywords=india&radios=&placeId=ChIJmeflRr8PlR4RWvO2jWjKfwE&address=South+Hills%2C+Johannesburg+South%2C+South+Africa&amenities=outdoor+space%2Cdryer%2Cpets+allowed%2Claundry+in+building%2Cfurnished%2Ccovered+parking%2Celevator%2Cwasher%2Cstove

I can see three options:

either params somehow still returns amenities when converted to string (try console.log(pathname + '?' + params) right before navigation),
or perhaps you perform some other navigation somewhere else,
or the navigation plays some magic tricks on you...

Try changing replace to push everywhere and definitely take a closer look at browsing history to see if you can find correct urls there.

You are right .The issue was related to the navigation logic written in another reset filter.

Try this
const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
setSearchParams({});

